# Extract text coordinates from iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I want to select a region from an iframe and send the coordinates to the backend. More specifically what I want to do is let the user select an area from a file(pdf) where a table is present. How do I go about doing this?

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://github.com/tapmodo/Jcrop and it's demos.

```
<Iframe src="" id="frame"/>
```

And the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function($){

  $('#frame').Jcrop({
    onChange:   showCoords,
    onSelect:   showCoords
  });

});

// Simple event handler, called from onChange and onSelect
// event handlers to show an alert, as per the Jcrop 
// invocation above

function showCoords(c)
{
  alert('x='+ c.x +' y='+ c.y +' x2='+ c.x2 +' y2='+ c.y2)
  alert('w='+c.w +' h='+ c.h)
};

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it only shows me the coordinates if I click on the edge of the iframe and not when I want to select pieces from the pdf

Comment: Pieces from the pdf .. mean rectangle which has start (x,y) and end(x,y)

Comment: Yes, that is what I need

Comment: this library already does that .. please press and hold press with move to select the area

Comment: I manage to do it but the selection can only start if I begin from an edge. Another thing I want to ask is if I can obtain the coordinates relative to the document and not the iframe. Thanks